# Android Studio - Configure image asset

Tags: android, android-studio, uiimageasset

I create icons with Android Studio, but I can use only **circle** or **square**...
Where I can find **squircle** and **rounded square**?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive)

> Android 8.0 (API level 26) introduces adaptive launcher icons, which
>   can display a variety of shapes across different device models. For
>   example, an adaptive launcher icon can display a circular shape on one
>   OEM device, and display a `squircle` on another device. Each device OEM
>   provides a mask, which the system then uses to render all adaptive
>   icons with the same shape. Adaptive launcher icons are also used in
>   shortcuts, the Settings app, sharing dialogs, and the overview screen.

Unlike the png file that you can visibly see its shape, the foreground layer file (ic_***_foreground.xml) is intrepreted as `circle` or `squircle` based on the mask provide by the device you are viewing it from. Hence you can say the file is both your `squircle and rounded squares`.